# git different directories between branches

Tags: php, git, directory, branch, vendor-branch

i'm struggling with the following situation:

There is one directory with two branches: master and L5.4
master uses Laravel 5.3, L5.4 uses Laravel 5.4

Main difference is the Laravel source (within the vendor dir) for version 5.3 and 5.4, ie for the master branch i'd have to use vendor/laravel (5.3) and for the L5.4 branch it would be vendor/laravel (5.4).
But afaik i cannot install both version within the vendor directory, so how can i handle it that?
Could it be that this is only possible using two different directories for both brnaches (as it would be using eg svn) or is there an other possibilty to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

`vendor/` should not be under source control. What should be different between the two branches is `composer.json` where you would define specific versions of the required libraries.

Comment: `vendor/` is in my gitignore, ie not versioned.

Maybe i explained it not clear enough.

what i mean is, if i'm working with my source, using master needs Laravel 5.3 and when i'm switching branch to L5.4 it should use Larvel 5.4.'

Since there is only 1 vendor directory with one Laravel installation in it how can i make it using either version of Laravel depending on the brnach

Comment: @frezno Adding `vendor/laravel` to git would solve your problem.

Comment: @jeroen - i thought about this as well, and started trying it already.   Unfortunately not successfully yet. One problem of Laravel is it's dependencies of other packages, sometimes of a certain version number and two other files (composer.lock and services) which will be changed accordingly.  
Might work though with some changes.

More of a no-brainer though would be using two different directories. Something i'd prefer to avoid.

Comment: @frezno Or you add everything to Git :-)

Comment: thought about that as well, @jeroen - but that will make committing and pushing a pita

Comment: @frezno how often do you need to switch between master and L5.4? I mean, is it a big deal to do `php composer.json install` every time you switch branch?

Comment: well @iloo , i'm working more or less simultaniously on both versions (branches), so i don't think that's very convenient. Another option might be to use composers repositories, eg vcs or package or something like that. Have to try. But until now it seems that the least time-consuming/easiest method would be to give each branch its own directory.